# How to get custom attribute value from a radcomboboxitem when an item is selected with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Here is my code:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlServicesRequested" runat="server" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" Skin="Vista" OnClientSelectedIndexChanging="setQtyReq"></telerik:RadComboBox>

function setQtyReq(combo, eventArgs) {
var Combo = $find("<%= ddlServicesRequested.ClientID %>");
var index= eventArgs.get_item().get_index();
}

Me.ddlServicesRequested.Items.Insert(0, New RadComboBoxItem("-- Select One --", "0"))
Dim dt1 As DataTable = GetDataTable("myStoredProcedure")
For Each dr As DataRow In dt1.Rows
  Dim rcbi As New RadComboBoxItem()
  rcbi.Text = dr("Text")
  rcbi.Value = dr("Value")
  rcbi.Attributes("Min") = dr("MinQty")
  rcbi.Attributes("Max") = dr("MaxQty")
  Me.ddlServicesRequested.Items.Add(rcbi)
Next
```

Here I have the radcombobox that is being populated with two custom attributes, Min and Max.  When the user selects an item the setQtyReq javascript function get called and I am able to get the radcombobox and the index of the selected item.  My problem I am having is that I can't figure out a way to get the values of the custom attributes.  How can I get the values of the custom attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do it:

```
function setQtyReq(combo, eventArgs) {
    var item = eventArgs.get_item();
    var min = item.get_attributes().getAttribute("Min");
    var max = item.get_attributes().getAttribute("Max");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-custom-attributes.html

```
<script language="javascript">
function setQtyReq(combo, eventArgs) {
var Combo = $find("<%= ddlServicesRequested.ClientID %>");
var index= eventArgs.get_item().get_index();
alert(Combo.Items[index].Attributes.Max);
alert(Combo.Items[index].Attributes.Min);
}
</script>
```

Looks like the above will work.

Comment: Wouldnd't that just return attributes of the radcombobox, not the item?   I have seen that link but I can't get anything on that page to work.

Comment: Made an amendment to my answer.  Hopefully this does it.

Comment: How can i set the value of the attribute please? i can get the value now but how can i set it through javascript?